# Extracting text from cell that is separated by lines

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am new to this sort of task, and I am very confused with how to extract some text from Cell.

This sounds very basic, but let me explain. I have exported some information on some roles for some of my employees, but it has put all of the information into a single cell in the following format:

```
Production Line




Working with Operations Manager




Oversee Production Line
```

and so on.

Problem is this that this is all separated by spaces and lines. Is there a way to separate the information into however many paragraphs there are, each into an individual cell?

Again, let me explain.

```
Cell A1 - Production Line
Cell A2 - working with operations Manager
Cell A3 - Oversee Production Line
```

Another problem, there is an undetermined number of characteristics.

Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the text is in cell B1 (can be easily changed) you could use VBA to do it:

```
Sub ExtractFromCell()

    Dim lines() As String
    Dim i As Integer, a As Integer

    a = 1
    lines = Split(Range("B1"), Chr(10))

    For i = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
        If lines(i) <> "" Then
            Cells(a, 1) = lines(i)
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Michal, I tried this and it didn't manage to get the result that I was looking for.

Comment: Hi, can you explain in more detail please?  The output of this macro is exactly as specified in the question.  You have to change "B1" in the code the address of the cell you want to process.  Cheers, Michal